# Delphi Synchronize a table

Tags: delphi

This application runs on a tablet within a network. I have a Button that adds a record to a table:

```pascal
procedure TTurnosList.CornerButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with D_Turnos do
  begin
    TurnosSocios.Insert;
    TurnosSociosCod_Socio.Value := SociosCod_Socio.Value;
    Cod_Socios_Esperando.Add(IntToStr(D_Turnos.SociosCod_Socio.Value));
    TurnosSocios.Post;

    TurnosSocios.ApplyUpdates();
    TurnosSocios.CommitUpdates;
    ConexionTurnos.Commit;
  end;
end;
```

On the other hand, from other PCs they can update the same table. And with a `TIdTCPServer` I have to update the view of said table, which I do like this:

```pascal
procedure TD_Turnos.Tablet_IdTCP_ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  S: String;
begin
  S := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;
  if S <> '' then
  Begin
    TurnosSocios.Close;
    TurnosSocios.Open;
    TurnosList.Cod_Socios_Esperando.Delete(StrToInt(S));
  End;
end;
```

The question is, how do I synchronize them to avoid conflicts?

Comment: Your q lacks at least four important details: 1.  What are the datatypes of the components in your code.  2. Where is the server data located.  3.  What kind of RDMS is storing the data.  4.  What does `TurnosList.Cod_Socios_Esperando.Delete(StrToInt(S))` do?

Comment: In asynchronous execution always could be conflicts. The question is wrong : you can NOT avoid conflicts. You can handle conflicts in scenarios. There are a large amount of books about this problem. Search for presistence, ORM. When your operation collides with another parallel operation, most of the cases an exception raises. You have to catch it, inform the user and refresh the interface for her/him.